# How do I make custom (print) text draggable in Raphael JS 2.0?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I recently updated to Raphael JS 2.0 and now my text dragging is laggy.

before (1.5): http://jsfiddle.net/jedateach/vZN72/

after (2.0): http://jsfiddle.net/jedateach/YyvSm/

Perhaps someone can fork my jsfiddle to show how it should be done?

Comment: Can be a bug or additional option in Raphael?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Raphael 2.0, instead of [Translate](http://raphaeljs.com/2.0/#Element.translate), you should make use of the [Transform](http://raphaeljs.com/2.0/#Element.transform) function, which adds a matrix transformation to the svg element.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/jedateach/ZR5uf).

Note that the use of "..." in the transform string will append the previous transformations. If you want to store multiple transformations such as size and rotation, you'll need to store the current values, and exclude "...".

Comment: Jason ... Jed ... your answer looks promising.  However ... the text is basically jumping away in your JSfiddle example.  when I try to apply your asnwer to my situation my circle and my text jump to the bottom lower corner.  i get an error in Firebug that ... text.oBB is undefined.  can you shed some light on this?

Comment: i've found a way around the error in Firebug (which also appeared in Chrome).  however the text and circle that i'm trying to drag are both hopping down to the lower right hand corner when i try to drag.